# Is it possible to limit the rate of key strokes on windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, water-damage, keystrokes

I damaged both my keyboard and mouse and when I now press certain buttons, they get pressed twice or three times in a couple millisecond interval. Is there an option in windows that disables such fast key-stroke repetition?

Comment: _Control Panel_ -> Keyboard; _Control Panel_ -> Mouse

Comment: @JosefZ no option for this there